# 'toto' object has no attribute 'draw' error Python

Tags: python, oop

There is my code:

```
import random

class toto():
  def whatgametype(self, userinput):
    if userinput == '5 out of 35':
      numslist = list(range(1, 36))
      return numslist
    if userinput == '6 out of 42':
      numslist = list(range(1, 43))
      return numslist
    if userinput == '6 out of 49':
      numslist = list(range(1, 50))
      return numslist
    else:
      numslist = list(range(1, 36))
      return numslist
    
    def draw(numslist: list, newlist: list, longoftrys):
      if longoftrys <= len(numslist):
        longoftrys+=1
        rand_idx = random.randint(0, len(numslist)-1)
        random_num = numslist[rand_idx]
        return newlist.append(random_num)
      else:
        pass
    def secondtier(secondtiernum, longoftrys, numslist: list):
      if secondtiernum <= 1 and longoftrys > len(numslist):
        longoftrys == 0
      else:
        pass

game = toto()
userinput = input('Which type of toto do you prefer?')
newlist = []
numslist = []
longoftrys = 0
numslist.append(game.whatgametype(userinput))
newlist.append(game.draw(numslist, newlist, longoftrys))
```

when I am pressing run I have same error: `'toto' object has no attribute 'draw'`. How to fix it?

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code and the error traceback? You call `game.whatgametype` before `game.draw` but the class you have posted doesn't have that method either

Comment: There it is - do not look at symbols at bottom - I have too much code

Comment: Your `draw` method is indented one too many levels, it's being defined at the end of the `whatgametype` method and not on the class. Reduce the indentation of the entire draw method by one "level" (2 spaces)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues -

1. Indentation is wrong for `draw` and `secondtier` methods which are coming under `whatgametype` method not in class's scope -> This resulting in `object has no attribute`
2. Once you correct above one, you will get `TypeError` because `draw` and `secondtier` is not correctly tied up with class. Either you make them `staticmethod` (if you don't want to use self in method) or pass `self` as first argument.

This should work -

```
class toto():
    def whatgametype(self, userinput):
        if userinput == '5 out of 35':
            numslist = list(range(1, 36))
            return numslist
        if userinput == '6 out of 42':
            numslist = list(range(1, 43))
            return numslist
        if userinput == '6 out of 49':
            numslist = list(range(1, 50))
            return numslist
        else:
            numslist = list(range(1, 36))
            return numslist

    @staticmethod
    def draw(numslist: list, newlist: list, longoftrys):
        if longoftrys <= len(numslist):
            longoftrys+=1
            rand_idx = random.randint(0, len(numslist)-1)
            random_num = numslist[rand_idx]
            return newlist.append(random_num)
        else:
            pass

    @staticmethod
    def secondtier(secondtiernum, longoftrys, numslist: list):
        if secondtiernum <= 1 and longoftrys > len(numslist):
            longoftrys == 0
        else:
            pass

game = toto()
userinput = input('Wich type of toto do you prefer?')
newlist = []
numslist = []
longoftrys = 0
numslist.append(game.whatgametype(userinput))
newlist.append(game.draw(numslist, newlist, longoftrys))
```